# How can I split this?

Tags: java, split

I want to split function in java.But it s not working good.

```
 String mystring = "ersin#$gulbahar#$ev";
 String [] scripts=  mystring.split("#$"); //it does not split.
```

how can i fix this?

Comment: Your problem stems from the fact that split uses regular expressions and $ is a special character in the regex. To treat it like a literal instead of special character, you need to escape it with \\ as done in the answer below.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
String mystring = "ersin#$gulbahar#$ev";
String[] scripts = mystring.split("#\\$");
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(scripts));
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
[ersin, gulbahar, ev]
```

Comment: Does java.util.Arrays have a toString for an array of Strings?

Comment: @squiguy yes it has a toString method for every arbitrary object type. Since `String` also overrides toString it works correctly.

Comment: @ThomasJungblut I knew about Object, I just wanted to clarify for the person asking just in case he would use it.  So yes, you are correct.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
mystring.split("#\\$")
```

the split method uses a Regex to split the text, a $ character has other mean in a regex

Answer (score 1):

`split` takes a regular expression as a parameter, and `$` is a special character in a regular expression meaning "match the end of the string".

Since you want to match a literal `$`, not the end of the string, you need to escape it with a backslash: `mystring.split("#\\$");` should work.

Answer (score 0):

Escape $ in your expression: split() takes a regular expression as parameter! Common issue...